# why my image view and text view in secomd framgent empty?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm

i get list of image and text data from api in first fragment then when user pick image it's go to second fragment and show image and text[first-fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq1Vx.jpg)
github.com/AzAlhobayyeb/Images.git
i tried to link fragments with live data didn't use arguments[second-fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nG1OP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's like the imagePicked in the 2nd Fragment is null.I think the reason the viewModel is recreated in 2nd page.

Solution :

In the ImageDetailsFragment you using :

```
    private val viewModel: ImageViewModel by viewModels()
```

change to this :

```
    private val viewModel: ImageViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Comment: thx for help I didn't noticed this